# Allow single swipe to show notification and control center, even when hiding iOS7 status bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, statusbar, uistatusbar

If status bar is hidden on iOS7, it forces the user to swipe twice to show both Notification Center and Control Center. It shows a small drag-button.

Is there a way to disable this behavior i.e. status bar is hidden, but just single swipe from top or bottom of screen makes it show the Notification Center and Control Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but currently, there is no public API for manipulating the behavior of the notification center.